# Create a truly headless QApplication instance

Tags: c++, macos, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I have a Qt 5.8 (via PyQt5) application whose many tests require a live `QApplication` instance in order to test gui widget interactions.

However on my new Mac OS X (10.11.6) machine when running these tests windows are constantly being created and destroyed, causing the entire system's UI to become highly unstable (although the tests pass as expected).

My tests do not even call `QApplication.exec()` - the `QApplication()` constructor is enough to cause this. On my linux machine this is no issue, as windows are not created (at least under my X configuration).

`QCoreApplication` is not an option as actual GUI widgets need to be created and worked with. Attempts to swap the two cause massive test failures.

Is there a way in Qt 5.8 to create a truly headless `QApplication` instance without using `QCoreApplication`?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do much of anything with QWidgets unless you have a QApplication object first.  The real issue here is, why is the system's UI becoming unstable?  That sounds like a Qt or OS bug that you might want to take up with Apple or Qt's developers.

Comment: The issue, I think, is that as soon as `QApplication()` is called (even from within a terminal), Mac OS X considers it as a new GUI application being launched, so the terminal window loses focus and the active window name changes from whatever it was to "python" (the name of the host process). This occurs even when `QApplication.show()` or `QApplication.exec()` is never called, so a proper window is never even created. Naturally changes in focus dozens of times per second while running unittests will cause undesirable behavior.

Comment: @ayoon Does the answer you've gotten work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think the solution is to add the argument, `-platform offscreen` to the command line of the `QApplication`.

I have found the information [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#platformName-prop)

Suppose your application executable is named `app_exe`

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int argument_count = 3;
   char* argument[3];
   argument[0] = const_cast<char*>("app_exe");
   argument[1] = const_cast<char*>("-platform");
   argument[2] = const_cast<char*>("offscreen");
   QApplication app(argument_count, argument);
   return app.exec();
}
```

As a result, you should have your application running but without showing any GUI. To see if the application is running, you shall list all running tasks and your application shall be within them.

Comment: Also looks like the "minimal" platform might be a good choice: "you can use the plugin to run GUI applications in environments without a GUI, such as servers".