# How to run a Qt application in headless mode (without showing my GUI)

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, qt5, qapplication

I have a QT application based on a `QApplication` and supposing that my application has a complex GUI (`QDialog`, `QMainWindow`...).

My Application can run in two modes:

- with GUI
- in headless mode

I would like to know how I can launch the application in headless mode (that is to say without GUI visible)

From a very basic code, below, what argument shall I have to allow this?

```cpp
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // which option should I add to argv to run in headless mode
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Use `QCoreApplication` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I effectively could use it but some parts of the code need QApplication as the application shall run under the two modes GUI and headless.

Comment: Similar to (unanswered) [create-a-truly-headless-qapplication-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686691/create-a-truly-headless-qapplication-instance)

Comment: I've never used Qt myself but perhaps creating a custom `QStyle` (or `QCommonStyle`) that renders _nothing_ and set that with `QApplication::setStyle(new CustomStyle);` before `QApplication app(argc, argv);` could be an option?

Comment: I have found a workaround, I posted it in the older question. May be this one will get deleted for duplicate

Comment: Which parts of `QApplication` do you need in head-less mode which are not provided by `QCoreApplication`? If head-less is an essential requirement for your application, then you might also re-design your application to separate the parts needed for head-less and the parts for GUI respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options here. Either you need a Qt Console Application or you need a headless GUI Application.

You will find truly running a GUI in headless mode rather tricky. This applies in case you need to run the very same app in a Linux system which does not have the installed GUI libraries, like a minimal setup. Without extensive xorg and/or EGL libraries you'll find it impossible.

But fear not, you can do it with minimal impact by using either the Qt VNC platform plugin or with with the help of [Xvfb](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). So in short

## Solution 1: Hide it with Qt's VNC plugin

```
$ QT_QPA_PLATFORM="vnc"  ./my-app
```

it's the same as

```
$ ./my-app -platform vnc
```

You'll find that you software has a GUI but it's running in headless mode, in order to view the GUI you just connect to it with any vncviewer.

## Solution 2: Avoid dependencies with Qt's VNC plugin

The same as the other solution, and you can just hide your GUI by not showing it.

## Solution 3: Nullify render with offscreen render

This is rather similar to VNC but you'll get a totally null output, no way for GUI interaction:

```
$ ./my-app -platform offscreen
```

## Solution 4: Run Xvfb and launch it there

You can run a fake Xorg server and run things over there.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
./myapp &
```

From the given solutions I'd prefer the offscreen render, but your Qt compilation might not have the plugin or it might ask for xcb or egl libraries. It's your choice.

Comment: rather run it with
xvfb-run ./myapp